# sum of unbiased dice

Tags: divisor-sum

Two unbiased dice are rolled and the numbers obtained are added. In this way, you have a better chance of getting numbers whose sum is:
a} 11
b} 10
c} 9
d} 8
e} 7

I did my sums and it is giving alternative "b" However, the feedback here, in the question, is reporting that it is alternative "e"...

what do you think? The answer to the question is wrong or I was really wrong... By my calculations, the answer is 8...

observation.: I put "divisor sum" in the tag because I didn't know, for sure, what to put.

Comment: The "average" die roll is a $3\frac 12$.  Although 3.5 will never come up, it points to the central tendency.  The most likely outcome from 2 dice is  $2\cdot 3.5 = 7.$  The "average" roll on 3 dice is 10.5.  But, as 10.5 is not actually possible, 10 and 11 are equally likely and the most likely rolls.

Comment: Roll the dice one at a time.  Suppose your first roll is a $1$.  What are the chances that your total ends up as $7, 8, 9, 10, \text { or } 11$?

Comment: thank you guys! I understood.